# MVC Razor Buttons

Tags: events, asp.net-mvc-3, button, razor

Hi i am new to MVC Razor

I was trying to do a page with 3 Button insert,delete and update.

My view looks like

```
        <div>    
          @using (Html.BeginForm())
           {

                <input type="button" class="button1" value="Insert" />
                <input type="button" class="button1" value="Delete" />
                <input type="button" class="button1" value="Update" /> 
           }
        </div>
```

And my controller is like

```
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
              return View();
       }
```

How i will get the events of these button in my controller so that i will be able to write the logic for each button. Please help me to get the coding or any suitable link which will  help to solve this problem.

Thanks
San

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit]

to re-itterate my point in the comments on the other answers: when you BIND LOGIC to the VALUE of a BUTTON in C# you are binding your C# code to that language.

Imagine you have the Save button in the english version as:

```
<input type="submit" value="Insert" name='button' />
```

and in your code you are going to switch using the value:

```
public ActionResult Index(string button)
{
    switch (button)  
    {
        case "Insert": ...
        case "Update": ...
        case "Delete": ...       
    }

    return View();
}
```

Now - when that form is viewed in another language - what do you think will happen?!?!

here is the welsh html output:

```
<input type="submit" value="Mewnosod" name='button' />
```

and the german:

```
<input type="submit" value="Einfügen" name='button' />
```

How is that EVER going to work?!

Globalization IS NOT A SEPERATE ISSUE!!!!

your action will look like this if you use this method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string button)
{
    switch (button)  
    {
        case "Insert": ...
        case "Update": ...
        case "Delete": ...     
        case "Einfügen": ...  
        case "Mewnosod": ....
        .... a load of other languages for each action type - 
    }

    return View();
}
```

please... seriously....

[/edit]

Here's my MVC Action Selector code: [Asp.Net Mvc action selector](http://iwayneo.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/aspnet-mvc-action-selector-with-list.html)

In essence you need an action selector class:

```
/// <summary>
/// AcceptParameterAttribute to enable submit buttons to execute specific action methods.
/// </summary>
public class AcceptParameterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value to use in submit button to identify which method to select. This must be unique in each controller.
    /// </summary>
    public string Action { get; set; }
 
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerContext">The controller context.</param>
    /// <param name="methodInfo">Information about the action method.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the action method selection is valid for the specified controller context; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
 
        var req = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
 
        return req.Form.AllKeys.Contains(this.Action);
 
    }
}
```

Which works off the name you give the button.

You can then decorate the actions with:

```
[AcceptParameter(Action = "Edit")]
public ActionResult Person_Edit(PersonViewModel model){
...
}
```

Switching in the action is dirty - this is a much cleaner approach. I think much more natural too.

Comment: here is an updated version of that code with list (databound) support: http://blogs.sonatribe.com/wayne/2011/06/15/171/

Comment: I have tried this... But i am getting an error message Like  "Sample.Controllers.AcceptParameterAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: ooops sorry! my mistake - you need to use the optional args method:  [AcceptParameter(Action = "Edit")]

Comment: configuration over convention method for mvc

Comment: i think convention over configuration is what we're aiming for as a community no? this is what got Ruby so popular - and the reason why .NET is playing catchup :)

Comment: Hi iwayneo. I have tried the same. But it always calling the index method.... I copy and pasted AcceptParameterAttribute.cs class and my view is like  '@using (Html.BeginForm()){ <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" /> }' and controller ' [AcceptParameter(Action = "Delete")]
        public ActionResult Person_Edit(emp model)
         {
             return View();
         }'

Comment: you need to use the MVC actionname attribute in conjunction with my AcceptParameter attribute - this will tell the MVC framework how to route your request      :                                   [HttpPost]
[ActionName("index")]
[AcceptParameter(Action = "Delete")]

Comment: why would you down vote this without giving a reason!! i give up on this site.

Comment: Fixed the link in the post :)

Answer (score 9):

Give the buttons a name:

```
<div>    
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
     <input type="button" name="button" class="button1" value="Insert" />
     <input type="button" name="button" class="button1" value="Delete" />
     <input type="button" name="button" class="button1" value="Update" /> 
 }
</div>
```

And use that in your action:

```
public ActionResult Index(string button)
{
    switch (button)  
    {
        case "Insert": ...
        case "Update": ...
        case "Delete": ...       
    }

    return View();
}
```

With all that said, I wouldn't use this approach.  I'd modify the form action on the fly to different controller actions (using `Url.Action`) hooking that code up to click handlers using jQuery.

Comment: +1 just for that last sentence. This is why i hate web forms - not because of the technology, because of how the event-driven thinking has brainwashed .net web developers, we have totally forgot about what HTTP is all about. developers of MVC need to basically unlearn a lot of their web forms vision of thinking.

Comment: -1 because the switch is dirty! although i'm +1 on the above comment :)

Comment: this option also breaks if the site is multi lingual - which is what the web is for no?

Comment: @cvista - valid points, but you need to understand it is an assumption that developers should understand localization as a common concept, so it need not be repeated in an answer

Comment: but my answer addresses these issues - so worth mentioning no? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353511/mvc-razor-buttons/6354575#6354575 :)

Comment: also - thinking about what you said - what you're saying is that there should be a separate action for save/edit/update/delete in each language?

Comment: @cvista - sounds like you are pining for rep points. :) Anyway, there should be a seperate action method for each CRUD action, preferably with the appropriate http verb attribute (REST). the URL's dont need to be localized, since you should be redirecting afterwards anyway (PRG). It's the button text that should be localized. So there should be 4 action methods.

Comment: But we're switching off the button text in this method!!! (aint nuthin wrong with a bit of rep++ to start the day! :D )

Comment: i dont think you're getting my point - i'm not randomly spinning off about globalization - he;s binding the logic to the VALUE of the button - do you not understand how that will break?

Answer (score 2):

Here is improved AcceptParameterAttribute, if you are using localization as I do

```
public class AcceptParameterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type ResourceType { set; get; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        if (ResourceType != null)
        {
            ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);
            return request.Form[Name] == resourceManager.GetString(Value);
        }
        return request.Form[Name] == Value;
    }
}
```

Usage similar to DisplayAttribute

```
[AcceptParameter(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "submit", Value = "Search")]
```

and button

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="@Resources.Search" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to read some simple tutorial about MVC3 - it will give you opportunity to understand basic principles of MVC framework. You can start [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

Now to your question:  best approach is to call from each button some action in controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Insert", "Insert")
```

**or**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{Id=lineId}).
```

Then, when user clicks this link - he will get to correct view, which is ready to handle that task.

Comment: how do you think that will post to an action? HTTP GET is not a POST?!

Comment: Why do You think there is POST needed?

Comment: How else will the forms fields be sent to the server? are you misunderstanding the OPs intent?

Comment: I don't see any form fields in question. I don't see any need to handle single form with triple submit action buttons. From OPs question we see what he trying to do, but it is better to explain how would he do better. Of course, he maybe really need something like you provided in your answer: your answer is selected - so maybe it's true. BTW, my answer is based on part: "I'm new to Razor" So answer should be basic :-)

Comment: i think the form fields were implied :)