# MVC, what button pressed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model-view-controller, post, submit

In my MVC application I have several submit buttons insde one form tag. How can I indicate what exactly button hes been pressed in my controller with [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC Razor Buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353511/mvc-razor-buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple test for the button name since only one submit button will get posted at a time.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult MyForm (FormCollection form)
{
  bool isButton1 = form.AllKeys.Contains ("Button1");
  bool isbutton2 = form.AllKeys.Contains ("Button2");

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will give you what you're looking for:
[Multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)

You basically wrap each input in its own BeginForm/EndForm and assign it to seperate action methods.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not get them to POST to different controller methods?

If they do different things that would seemt o seperate concern better